# Installing MPICH on OS X 10.10

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I am very new to the C/C++ programming in an OS X environment. I am trying to install `MPICH3.14` on my laptop. However, it fails the configuration by indicating that "C compiler cannot create executables." Could someone help me?

```
    dhcp-10-101-50-155:Desktop apple$ cd mpich-3.1.4\ 2/
    dhcp-10-101-50-155:mpich-3.1.4 2 apple$ ./configure
    Configuring MPICH version 3.1.4
    Running on system: Darwin dhcp-10-101-50-155.wireless.northwestern.private       14.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
checking for icc... no
checking for pgcc... no
checking for xlc... no
checking for xlC... no
checking for pathcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... confdb/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
configure: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in `pwd`
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... no
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin14.1.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for icpc... no
checking for pgCC... no
checking for xlC... no
checking for pathCC... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin14.1.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for ifort... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pathf90... no
checking for pathf95... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for xlf2003... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if gfortran PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if gfortran static flag -static works... no
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gfortran linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin14.1.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if gfortran PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if gfortran static flag -static works... no
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gfortran linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin14.1.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
./configure: line 26051: test: /Users/apple/Desktop/mpich-3.1.4: binary operator expected
checking hcoll/api/hcoll_api.h usability... no
checking hcoll/api/hcoll_api.h presence... no
checking for hcoll/api/hcoll_api.h... no
checking for hcoll_init in -lhcoll... no
./configure: line 26435: test: /Users/apple/Desktop/mpich-3.1.4: binary operator expected
./configure: line 26441: test: /Users/apple/Desktop/mpich-3.1.4: binary operator expected
configure: RUNNING PREREQ FOR ch3:nemesis
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for getpagesize... (cached) yes
configure: ===== configuring src/mpl =====
./configure: line 27260: test: /Users/apple/Desktop/mpich-3.1.4: binary operator expected
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=NONE' --disable-versioning --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... confdb/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
configure: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in `pwd`
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... no
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin14.1.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking for inline... inline
checking for variable argument list macro functionality... yes
checking for gcov... gcov
checking whether the compiler supports __typeof(variable)... yes
checking stdio.h usability... yes
checking stdio.h presence... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking stdarg.h usability... yes
checking stdarg.h presence... yes
checking for stdarg.h... yes
checking ctype.h usability... yes
checking ctype.h presence... yes
checking for ctype.h... yes
checking search.h usability... yes
checking search.h presence... yes
checking for search.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/uio.h usability... yes
checking sys/uio.h presence... yes
checking for sys/uio.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking valgrind.h usability... no
checking valgrind.h presence... no
checking for valgrind.h... no
checking memcheck.h usability... no
checking memcheck.h presence... no
checking for memcheck.h... no
checking valgrind/valgrind.h usability... no
checking valgrind/valgrind.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/valgrind.h... no
checking valgrind/memcheck.h usability... no
checking valgrind/memcheck.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/memcheck.h... no
checking helgrind.h usability... no
checking helgrind.h presence... no
checking for helgrind.h... no
checking valgrind/helgrind.h usability... no
checking valgrind/helgrind.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/helgrind.h... no
checking drd.h usability... no
checking drd.h presence... no
checking for drd.h... no
checking valgrind/drd.h usability... no
checking valgrind/drd.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/drd.h... no
checking whether the valgrind headers are broken or too old... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking whether strdup needs a declaration... no
checking for snprintf... yes
checking whether snprintf needs a declaration... no
checking for strncmp... yes
checking whether strncmp needs a declaration... no
checking for putenv... yes
checking whether putenv needs a declaration... no
checking whether __attribute__ allowed... yes
checking whether __attribute__((format)) allowed... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating localdefs
config.status: creating include/config.h
config.status: include/config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing include/mplconfig.h commands
config.status: creating include/mplconfig.h - prefix MPL for include/config.h defines
config.status: include/mplconfig.h is unchanged
configure: ===== done with src/mpl configure =====
configure: sourcing src/mpl/localdefs
configure: ===== configuring src/openpa =====
./configure: line 27642: test: /Users/apple/Desktop/mpich-3.1.4: binary operator expected
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=NONE' --disable-versioning --with-atomic-primitives=auto_allow_emulation --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... confdb/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/apple/Desktop/mpich-3.1.4 2/src/openpa':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
configure: error: OpenPA configure failed
```

Comment: The error log mentions that more information is in config.log. "See `config.log' for more details". Could you post that file? (Perhaps on https://gist.github.com/ if it's too long)

Comment: @Lalaland Here is the configure log file . Thanks https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0f3b6c2a7fb2f150d296

Comment: Going off of this error ("gcc: error: 2/src/mpl/include: No such file or directory"), I think the problem is that you have spaces in your directory name. Could you try renaming "mpich-3.1.4 2" to be without the space?